# xf:submission: Populate Header Value From Current Context

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm wanting to populate the header in a xf:submission with a value from the current context.  Documentation says that an xpath expression can be used but doesn't provide any examples.

I've tried using xsl:value, seen below, but that doesn't populate anything.  Is that the correct syntax to populate xf:value?

```
<p:for-each href="#attachments" select="//attachment" root="attachments" id="post-document-pages">
    <p:processor name="oxf:xforms-submission">
        <p:input name="submission">
            <xf:submission 
                method="post" 
                resource="http://localhost:8080/is/document/{@documentId}/page" 
                serialization="application/octet-stream">
                <xf:header>
                    <xf:name>Resource-Name</xf:name>
                    <xf:value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@filename" />
                    </xf:value>
                </xf:header>
            </xf:submission>
        </p:input>
        <p:input name="request"  href="current()" />
        <p:output name="response" ref="post-document-pages" /> 
    </p:processor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `<xf:header>`, simply use:

```
<xf:value value="[your XForms expression here]"/>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I had tried adding value to xf:header, and like 10 other ways, but never tried that.  Thanks

Comment: @StephenDonnell Excellent! And thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: do you have an example of how you would use the value of a property from properties-local in a header?

Comment: @StephenDonnell Certainly: you can use the [`xxf:property()`](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-core.html#xxfproperty) function for this.